# Apply conditional formatting only when cell has a value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a template with conditionals, for example, if date cell is less than today, then fill cell with blue, the problem is my template has no values, but all columns are filled with blue.

Is there any way to teach Excel to apply that conditional formatting only when cell has a value? Thanks!

Comment: Use a formula: `=AND(A1<>"",A1<TODAY())`.

Comment: Can I use it if I have a range of cells which applies the same conditional? Like this `=$T:$T`

Comment: `=AND(T1<>"",T1<TODAY())` should work.

Comment: Enter a valid formula if I use this `=AND(T1<>"",T1<>TODAY())`

Comment: What type of condicional can I use with that formula? Less than won't work right?

Comment: Sorry typo, should be `<TODAY()`. And if the formula separator in your version of Excel is `;`, then you'll need to use that instead of a `,`.

Comment: It only works in `T1` cell, not the whole column, is it posible to do that? Like `=$T:$T`

Comment: Change the "applies to" range to the entire column. Don't use a full-column reference in the formula.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much